# How to make Visual Studio Code use path mappings for automatic imports?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to have absolute paths in my project to avoid ugly paths and to have constant imports wherever a file is in the project tree.

I have added this in the `tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
  "@myapp/*": ["*", "app/*"]
}
```

I can now have working imports like `import { ... } from '@myapp/...'` but the automatic imports from Visual Studio Code are still relative.

I tried this in the `settings.json` (as written in https://blog.angulartraining.com/path-mapping-with-typescript-cac16d12c416)

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

But it didn't help. How to make Visual Studio Code's automatic imports use the paths mapping. Also, is there a tool that would help me refactor all of my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Navigate to`File>Preferences>Settings>User Settings` on VSCode
2. Set `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have both - mapped paths & relative - after [PR #40637](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40637) you can use

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "shortest"
```